# Preventing DoS attacks from malicious protobuf packets

Tags: .net, security, protobuf-net

I'm currently writing a client/server application, using Google Protocol Buffers to encode the underlying messages. Since it's a .NET program, I'm using the protobuf-net library: it's fast, portable and well thought.

However, I'm a little concerned about potential DoS attacks. The server application will be facing the internet directly and the underlying protocol will be publicly documented. An attacker can very easily craft a packet to exhaust memory.

A simple example:

Given the following proto definition:

```
[ProtoContract]
class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

The following code will try to allocate a 2GB buffer for the `Bar` string:

```
byte[] bytes = { 0x0A, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x07 };
Serializer.Deserialize<Foo>(new MemoryStream(bytes));
```

Instantly resulting in a `OutOfMemoryException`. Of course, here it won't really matter: the runtime won't be able to allocate it (at least in a 32 bits process). Now craft multiple packets each allocating a few hundreds MB of memory, and watch normal operations fail because of the lack of memory. Sure, the memory will be reclaimed rapidly by the GC if the attacker doesn't send anything after the string length, but it's still too easy to increase memory pressure.

I'm aware that this issue isn't really specific to protobuf-net: any protocol using length-prefixed data will probably encounter the same problems. Usually, they're solved using arbitrary quotas. However, I didn't find any way to specify them in protobuf-net. For example, I'd like to specify that a string cannot exceed N characters, that a given list cannot have more M elements, etc.

Is there any easy solution to prevent this problem that I've missed (rather than making my own implementation or fork)?

Comment: I don't know if there is a better method, AFAIK for sure it can be done if you drop _normal_ parsing and you do it with _reflection_ (well at least as early validation): `reflection->FieldSize(foo, descriptor->FindFieldByName("Bar")) <= 1024)`. (sorry it's C++ syntax, I never used .NET version but I guess it's pretty similar).

Comment: I'm sure we could add quota support if it is a requirement... simply: it hasn't been yet.

Comment: @Adriano: I'm not sure protobuf-net supports this without parsing.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. Is it planned? Do you take pull requests?

Comment: @JulienLebosquain sadly I never used it so I don't know if it supports everything (but I'd guess it may be, reflection is pretty nice part).

Comment: @Julien "planned" is a matter of judging needs. It wasn't on my list of immediate things to do, but it also isn't necessarily a big change

Comment: @MarcGravell: Wouldn't it be possible to only allocate the memory if it is actually used? Even though an attacker could then still use up a lot of memory if he/she transmits a lot of memory it nonetheless makes the issue tolerable for most services.

Comment: @parseids to avoid resize / copying, it allocates the expected buffer and then fills data into the buffer. There is no great alternative, especially when talking about large data. It has to go *somewhere*, and that can't be your io buffer

Comment: Talk only to authenticated clients you trust. Then the malicious garbage packets will have no real-life occurrence. If you experience bad packets due to bugs in the client code then apply testing, code reviews etc.

Comment: It's not really an option here. There will be an official client, but a documented protocol and alternative clients expected - and encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The only two options I see for you, at the moment, is to dive into Protobuf-Nets code base and find where it parses the binary data. Which isn't exactly a bad idea if you're planning to use protocol buffers.

Or you can create your own classes for strings/lists/arrays with a static set length (not dynamic) so you don't send length prefixes over the internet which kind of defeats the purpose of using an efficient system such as Protobuf and messes up your architecture.